# setBackgroundColor() in Webview is not working

Tags: android, android-webview

I have created a webview with a transparent background.

```java
browser = new WebView(ActivityActivate.this);
browser.setBackgroundColor(0);

browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.addJavascriptInterface(new JavascriptInterface(), "javaInterface");               

browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
browser.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

browser.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://checkout.google.com", form, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
llPaymentButtons.addView(browser);
```

Here is the JavaInterface that should change the color of the background when the html form is submitted and all the checkboxes pass the test.

```java
/**
 * Interface for Javascript communication
 */
private class JavascriptInterface {

    //This is in fact used but from JavaScript
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public boolean checkboxPass() {
        if( acceptsConditions() && acceptsLicense() && acceptsRefundPolicy() ) {
            browser.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This does not work however, and the returned document still has a transparent background.  What am I doing wrong, it seems that `browser.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);` does nothing?

Comment: Are you sure that the code was executed at all? Have you set up a breakpoint on the set color line?

Comment: It was in fact executed but from the wrong Thread, it seems a Handler() fixed the issue

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can override `webview` background with `setbackgroundResource` method,

try like this you will get it,

```java
wv.setBackgroundColor(0);
wv.setBackgroundResource(color.blue);
wv.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Get this error - 11-16 18:59:09.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1113): FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewCoreThread
11-16 18:59:09.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1113): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: This is because I am doing it from the JavaScript Interface...Not sure what I should do...

Comment: you should use View.post() or Activity.runOnUiThread() methods. they run the Runnable on UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we could `webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)` in `onLayout()`, and then add `style="background-color:white"` into html element.